# Animations For Windows Applications

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, animation

Where can I find standard (licence free) animations like "Copy" for self implemented windows applications (avi,animated gif)?
Visual Studio has only few animations in its image library (unfortunately not the "Copy" animation).

Comment: A handful is built into Windows, so the Q becomes: how to read those std resources. (I don't know).

Comment: I personally find such animations annoying and useless. If you absolutely must do this, please allow users some way of turning them off.

Comment: @Dour High Arch: Unnecessary comment! I don't want a discussion about the sense of animations in applications! I don't need such advices!

Comment: @Elmex sorry, I second Dour's remark and I guess many others do, too

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd and @Dour High Arch: Point is: Dour is not helping answering the question. If we should question the purpose of every question being asked around here, SO wouldn't be what it is today. Be objective, and do you have relevant input on a question, put up an answer. If not, spend your time somewhere else.

Comment: @Peter not every question of course, but I reserve the right to question the purpose of *some* questions. And writing comments is a relatively harmless form of doing so (as opposed to downvoting or flagging)

Comment: @Sean - sure, but we should save such comments for the really bad questions. I think we agree that this question is not "bad" in that sense. Touting my own personal feelings towards animations in applications is really out of line in this context, it just adds noise which in some cases (like this one) offends other people. Suddenly, "just" writing comments wasn't harmless after all.

Comment: @peter I disagree, but I'll leave it at that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you download Resource Hacker and look for the desired resource in the `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll` file.
Look under the AVI section for the common AVIs used by windows.

---

Alternatively, if you have Visual Studio 2008 installed, look through the **Visual Studio Image Library**. There is a copy animation in there albeit it isn't the same as the one windows displays when a copy is in progress.

The VS image library can be found at `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\VS2008ImageLibrary`

Answer (score 1):

There are a few icon packs available through the Extension Manager in Visual Studio 2010, just search for "icon" in the Online Gallery. Not sure whether there are animated icons for the Copy operation, though.

Answer (score 1):

On WindowsXP, some of the animations can be found in the shell32.dll, you'll need to grab each one and see what it is as they only have resource IDs for them. However, **there is no documented API to access these resources and just opening shell32.dll and reading the resource is not recommended, nor can it be assumed what the format of the resource is**, see [this article by Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/10/26/485133.aspx) about this issue.

Technically, you could just extract the animation using a resource editor and add the animation to your application. However, there is almost certainly a copyright / licensing issue here - copying the resources and adding them to your application is certainly copyright infringement, and reading the resource from system32.dll to use in your application might be breaking the EULA. IANAL, so seek advice if this is for a non-personal project.